# Having trouble with django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path

Tags: django, heroku

"python manage.py collectstatic" is not working, I think it might not work for any file and this fa-brands-400.eot happened to be the first file.

Error:

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/Users/monica/music-emotion/static/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/monica/music-emotion/staticfiles)
```

Is settings.py supposed to be located in root or can it be in a subdirectory?
My settings.py has this at the end-

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join('me_main/static'),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error I just removed

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

and it works fine now.